# Facebook OpenGraphContent on swift3

Tags: swift, facebook

I have tried to integrate an Open Graph Story with the latest Facebook SDK for Swift but I receive an error "generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred"

```
let object: OpenGraphObject = [
    "og:type": "books.book",
    "og:title": "A Game of Thrones",
    "og:description": "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.",
    "books:isbn": "0-553-57340-3"
]
// Create an action
var action = OpenGraphAction(type: "book.reads")
action["books:book"] = object
// Create the content
var content = OpenGraphShareContent()
content.action = action
content.previewPropertyName = "books:book"
try ShareDialog.show(from: self, content: content) //Here i'm getting "generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred"
```

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: I am finding exactly the same issue but it does appear to me that this is the API that Facebook suggest is used?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from the [commit log](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/pulse/monthly), that module is no longer maintained. Instead, use the `FBSDKShareKit` module (e.g. from Cocoapods, with `use_frameworks!`). Then you should be able to do

```
import FBSDKShareKit

...

// Create an object
let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject.init(properties: [
    "og:type": "books.book",
    "og:title": "A Game of Thrones",
    "og:description": "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.",
    "books:isbn": "0-553-57340-3"
    ])

// Create an action
let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction.init()
action.actionType = "books.reads"
action.setObject(object, forKey: "books:book")

// Create the content

let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent.init()
content.action = action
content.previewPropertyName = "books:book"

FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
```